# What are Deadpool's Katanas made of?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the *Deadpool* movie, there is a scene where Deadpool throws one of his swords at Ajax's motorbike's front wheel and then Ajax proceeds to fly over the handle  bars. Then in the next scene Deadpool rams one of the swords through Ajax's shoulder and right through solid concrete. (4:42 in the clip below)

I can't realistically see even a high quality Katana being able to stand up to either of those situations, but being that it is a movie, were they made of some special material such as Adamantium or were they just really special steel blades that were really strong?

First and foremost I would like an answer that states what they were in the movie, but I also want to know what they were made of in the comics, as from my research I can't seem to get an accurate answer as to what they were actually made of.

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool%27s_Katanas#cite_note-Cable_.26_Deadpool_Vol_1_15-1 - Steel, but with an energy enhancement to make them stronger.

Comment: @Valorum, but some places state that they were made from Adamantium??? Also, was there anything about what they were made odf in the movie?

Comment: I think Adamantium version of it was only showcased in X-men origins wolverine where Adamantium are surgically attached to his arms to create the perfect "mutant slayer." In movie deadpool it is unclear what they are made of.

Comment: Correct, that Wiki link provides all the info you need. Pool's katanas are regular ol' steel, but he can charge them via his suit to make them harder. Only in the three universes listed on that page are they anything but, and only in X-Men Origins: Wolverine are they Adamantium.

Answer (score 10):

In the movie, there is no indication that Deadpool's katanas are anything but high-quality mundane swords.  Given his living situation and his no-doubt high ammunition costs, I do not believe Deadpool had the resources to acquire any exotic materials, and the rules of cinema would argue that if they were special we would see (or there would be a reference to) their acquisition on-screen.

I can certainly see a well-made katana (in a superhero universe) destroying a motorcycle's tires as seen without being significantly damaged.

At the referenced time point in the Youtube video you linked, we do absolutely see the katana punch through the concrete.  It appears undamaged.  Please note, though, that Deadpool has a significant amount of physical strength as well as considerable skill with a sword.  While unlikely, it is possible for a strong blow aimed correctly to pierce concrete.  This is especially true when the concrete is low-quality, old, and has been extensively weathered.

Please note that when Deadpool is dragged away afterwards he does not have his katanas back.  Both of them were abandoned or stolen.

When we next see Deadpool with his katanas, he has had a chance to return home and rearm.  I would guess he has a supply of katanas (or at least a backup pair) specifically because he uses them in damaging ways.